# Multiple Errors - formGroup expects a FormGroup Instance - Form working fine, but multiple errors displayed in console

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic-forms

I have a form which works perfectly after a delay of 3 seconds. In those 3 seconds, the form is filled with multiple errors along the count of 15 stating

`formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one`

`Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

What I understand is that the form population is based on the fact that API Call is successful and response is returned. While the response is not there, the form is not defined and hence the errors.

Question: What to do to get rid of this issue and best possible way to do it

HTML Template

```
  <div [formGroup]="productForm">
        <div class="r-package-list" formArrayName="packages">
          <div
            class="r-package-list-item"
            *ngFor="let package of packageForms.controls; let i = index"
            [formGroupName]="i"
          >
            <div class="formArrayControlDiv">
              <label class="Package-Name-Label"
                ><input
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="Package-Selection-Checkbox"
                  formControlName="packageCheckBox"
                />
              </label>
              <input
                type="number"
                formControlName="packageQuantity"
              />
              <input
                readonly
                type="text"
                formControlName="packagePrice"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The TS File

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.apiService.getPackages(id).then((result: any) => {
        this.createForm(result.data);
      });

  }


  // Creating a Product Form
  createForm(data) {
    const arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      arr.push(this.packageArrayFunction(data[i]));
    }

    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      packages: this.fb.array(arr)
    });
  }

  // Creating a Dynamic Package Array
  packageArrayFunction(packages): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      packageCheckBox: [false],
      packageQuantity: [''],
      packagePrice: [packages.basic_price + '/' + packages.base_unit]
    });
  }

  get packageForms() {
    return this.productForm.get('packages') as FormArray;
  }
```

Comment: try put *ngIf on the form group element until you have all the data to show it.

Comment: Is that the best approach to do this. The ngIf works but the question is that is this the best approach ?

Comment: You can have an observable of formGroup and use it like `[formGroup]="productForm$ | async"`

Comment: @Axar say you that `<div *ngIf="productFrom"  [formGroup]="productForm">...</form>`

Comment: You can't render the form without the form object being there.. Up to you on how you make that work. What Gilsdav suggest will work too; however I don't see why would avoid using ngIf. You can initialize the form productForm object without any data and append data to it once it's loaded. That way it renders successfully as empty. Then you'll need some kind of loading..etc..etc.